# My wifi has been disabled and i dont know why

Tags: wifi

Im just installing this linux for the first time and i dont kno why my wifi cannot be activate

```
       *-network DISABLED
            description: Wireless interface
            product: BCM43227 802.11b/g/n
            vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            logical name: wlp2s0
            version: 00
            serial: c0:18:85:6b:87:1b
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
            resources: irq:17 memory:f0500000-f0503fff
```

Comment: Long shot: It could be that secure boot is enable in BIOS. Try switch it off.

Comment: its already off, all driver has been installed, my driver is BCM43227, my laptop is acer 4752Z